# Android different sensor delays fail for multiple sensors

Tags: android, delay

If I set different sampling rates (delays) for different sensors, like:

```
    SensorMgr.registerListener(this, accSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
SensorMgr.registerListener(this, magneticFieldSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
SensorMgr.registerListener(this, orientationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Android chooses SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (the fastest among the given delays) for all the sensors. i.e. the onSensorChanged() is called for all sensors at SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST. Is this a bug or something?

I have even tried different classes of each sensor listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use different instance of sensor manager for each different sensors. From your code i see that you used same sensorManager instance to all 3 sensor.